# How to split on a delimiter in python preserving the delimiter

Tags: python, url, split, delimiter

so what i wanna do here is basically i have a file with a list of url endpoints, and i wanna split the links in the file on the slash delimter, basically generating sub-endpoints of endpoints, example:

```
https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3
```

and i would want to get this:

```
https://www.somesite.com/path1/
https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/
https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3
```

i know how to achieve this in bash, but not with python, i tried using split function but it's very limited in my hands. i hope i can get some help here, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to split by a `/`, then slice the result and join back:

```
>>> url = 'https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3'
>>> parts = url.split('/')
>>> ['/'.join(parts[:p+1]) for p in range(3, len(parts))]
['https://www.somesite.com/path1', 'https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2', 'https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3']
```

Answer (score 0):

For the generic "split", but keeping the delimiter, you can use the `str.partition` method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition

Now, for your specific use case, where you want the full intermediate strings as a list, you can write some code, starting with the urllib.parse to get the URL initia;l part, without worrying about corner cases, and them manipulate the path with `for`, `split` and `join`.

```
url = "https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3"
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse

path = (components:= list(urlparse(a)))[2]
path_comps_str = ""
path_comps = [path_comps_str:= path_comps_str + f"/{comp}" for comp in path.split("/")[1:]]
for path in path_comps:
    url_parts = components[:]
    url_parts[2] = path
    all_urls.append(urlunparse(url_parts))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
link = "https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3"
splitted = link.split('/')
newLink = splitted[0] + "//" + splitted[2] + "/"
for i in range(3, len(splitted)):
    newLink += splitted[i]
    if i != len(splitted)-1:
        newLink += "/"
    print(newLink)
```

The output code is:

```
https://www.somesite.com/path1/
https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/
https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3
```

But the last `/` of links is not needed so you could write it as:

```
link = "https://www.somesite.com/path1/path2/path3"
splitted = link.split('/')
newLink = splitted[0] + "//" + splitted[2]
for i in range(3, len(splitted)):
    newLink += "/" + splitted[i]
    print(newLink)
```